# Is there any way to set the Featured image in wordpress post editor, using a Getty images embed code

Tags: shortcode, post-thumbnails, embed

I want to be able to use a Getty images embed code to set the featured image (Post thumbnail) in my wordpress post editor.

Is there any way of doing this? I understand that Wordpress doesn't allow the featured image to be set by shortcode.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Unfortunately you question is not very clear. What embed code are you talking about? What does it look like? Where does it come from?

Comment: I'm talking about the Getty images embed code. The featured image (post thumbnail) in the wordpress post editor can only be set using a JPG or PNG file. Is there any way that the featured image (post thumbnail) could be set by using a Getty images embed code?